# Openconnect XML response has no “auth” node and failed to obtain WebVPN cookie on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn, openconnect

After successfully installing `openconnect` using `apt` on Ubuntu 18.04, when I try to connect to VPN using

```
$ openconnect https://xxx.xx.xxx/
XML response has no "auth" node 
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

I don't have more details of given error. Can anyone provide me with solution of given VPN error?

Answer (score 0):

On my system, Ubuntu 18.04 did not support the old Openconnect VPN version **7.2**. Upon updating it to version **8.2**, this problem was solved.

For more details on VPN configurations, visit [this website](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/4-1/globalprotect-app-new-features/new-features-released-in-gp-agent-4_1/globalprotect-app-for-linux/customize-portal-gateway-for-globalprotect-for-linux.html).